# このfはどういう働きをしてるのでしょうか？ → session.get(f’{base_url}?{qs}{page_num}')

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping

スクレイピングの勉強で以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

base_url = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/yyy'
qs = 'sort=desc&page='

for page_num in range(5):
    session = HTMLSession()
    resp = session.get(f'{base_url}?{qs}{page_num}')

    elems = resp.html.find('.product_title')
    print([i.text for i in elems])
```

こちらの8行目で書かれている `session.get(f’{base_url}?{qs}{page_num}')` の`'f'`がどのような働きをしているものなのか、また何と呼ばれているものなのでしょうか...？

大変初歩的な質問で恥ずかしい限りなのですが、ご教授いただきましたら幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます！

Comment: f-strings (フォーマット済み文字列リテラル) と言うそうです。詳しくは回答する方にお任せするとして、分からないコードをゼロから書かれたわけではないと思うので、参考にした元の情報を示されると良いと思います。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

文字列中に変数や式を埋め込むためのもので、「フォーマット済み文字列リテラル(f-strings)」と呼ばれるものです。
Python 3.6 から導入された機能で、`str.format()` を使うよりも短く記述することがきます。

```
# 以下は同じ出力が得られます。

# str.format() を使った場合
print('{}?{}{}'.format(base_url, qs, page_num))
# f-string を使った場合
print(f'{base_url}?{qs}{page_num}')
```

詳しくはリファレンスをご確認ください。
[Python 言語リファレンス](https://docs.python.jp/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)